# How does smart DNS proxy work?

Tags: dns, dns-servers

I have been looking on the web, but there aren't a detailed explanation on how it works and not the concept of what it is for. There are really two things that I don't understand.

1. How does it fake the client location?

   My understanding on DNS is that it resolves a URL into an IP and give it to the browser then the browser and the OS deals with connecting to that IP. So I don't quote understand how a smart DNS can fake clients location
2. Where do smart DNS fake the client location to?

   My guess is that they fake the client location to where the server that they are trying to connect locates but this does not ensures that it would unlock a region locked service si CE the server may just be located in other countries. Or would they have a list of region locked services and lists of where to fake the client location bit this also doesn't ensure that it has full list of services.

Comment: Is this in reference to this Wikipedia article?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_DNS_proxy_server

Comment: Yes and people seems to be selling this service using the name "smart dns"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a smart DNS, this is what happens. 
Let's suppose that you are in UK but want to access a blocked site `example.com` in US (whose ip address is `x.x.x.x`).

1. You query the smart DNS asking to resolve `example.com`
2. As the smart DNS provider knows that `example.com` is a blocked site, instead of resolving it as `x.x.x.x`, it resolves it as `y.y.y.y`.

`y.y.y.y` is a proxy server of the smart DNS provider which is in the US.
As a result you are connecting to `example.com`  by using the Smart DNS  proxy. In fact smart DNS are often called smart DNS proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

Smart DNS is just a fancy name for a DNS proxy. It does not change your IP.

It only works as long as the website relies only on DNS to do location-based routing. Were the website to actually check for the user's IP at every request, it would know the actual location of the user.